# After Microsoft 365 Apps for business update - Checkbox.value not initialized in macros - Run-time error '4120': Bad parameter

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

After you I completed the latest update of Microsoft Apps for business.

A "Run-time error '4120': Bad parameter" error is displayed when I test the value of my checkboxes!

```
 If ActiveDocument.FormFields("SignalSauvegarde").CheckBox.Value = False Then
```

[Run Time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx9NJ.png)

Under version 16.0.13628.20318, the code was still working!

I'm under version 16.0.13801.20240 (64bits) now and it doesn't work anymore !

The craziest thing in the story is that when I changed the checkbox options and make it available to users for example (checkbox enabled), the code passes ! but that's not the point !

[Options for checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkkBu.png)

Do you have any ideas?

What do you recommend?

Thank you in advance for your collaboration

Comment: I think you should ask a new question to get answers

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the `Default` property to find whether it is checked or not. The following example compares the current value with the default value of the check box named "Check1." If the values are equal, the `same` variable is set to `true`.

```
Dim ffTemp As FormField 
Dim same As Boolean 
 
Set ffTemp = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check1").CheckBox 
If ffTemp.Default = ffTemp.Value Then 
 same = True 
Else 
 same = False 
End If
```

Hopefully it helps!